# Finding expected value and variance of a random variable.

Tags: probability, statistics

Given $$X∼Bin(n,p_x)$$ and $$Y∼Bin(m,p_y)$$
and we have to find E[W] where W = 4X + 6Y for which I got
$$E[W]=4np_x+6mp_y$$ by using $$E[aX+bY]=aE[X]+bE[Y]$$
for variance I'm not sure whether to do it like this
$$Var[W]=E[(4X+6Y)^2]-[E[W]]^2=E[16X^2+48XY+36Y^2]-[E[W]]^2$$
or since we don't know whether X and Y are dependent or not, maybe another possibility is
$$Var[W]=Var[4X+6Y]=4^2Var[X]+6^2Var[Y]+2Cov[X,Y]$$                       $$=4^2Var[X]+6^2Var[Y]+2E[XY]−2E[X]E[Y]$$
$$=16E[X^2]+16[E[X]]^2+36E[Y^2]+36[E[Y]]^2+2E[XY]−2E[X]E[Y]$$
or are they both correct?

**Edit**: substituted a (-) for a (+) in the first formula for variance 
$$Var[W]=E[(4X+6Y)^2]+[E[W]]^2=E[16X^2+48XY+36Y^2]+[E[W]]^2$$ changed to 
$$Var[W]=E[(4X+6Y)^2]-[E[W]]^2=E[16X^2+48XY+36Y^2]-[E[W]]^2$$
as well as added the missing 2 in
$$Var[W]=Var[4X+6Y]=4^2Var[X]+6^2Var[Y]+2Cov[X,Y]$$                       $$=4^2Var[X]+6^2Var[Y]+E[XY]−E[X]E[Y]$$
$$=16E[X^2]+16[E[X]]^2+36E[Y^2]+36[E[Y]]^2+E[XY]−E[X]E[Y]$$
removed the statement the W depends on X,Y and clarified that we don't know whether X and Y are dependent or not.

Comment: You got one variance formula wrong. It should be $\text{Var}[W]=E[W^2]-(E[W])^2$.

Comment: $\operatorname{var}(X)=\mathbb E(X^2) - (\mathbb E(X))^2$.  You have "$+$" where you need "$-$". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks I make the edit to fix that mistake.

Comment: aslo you forgot the 2 after expanding the cov term, in your second approach

Comment: Yes, thank you, I'll make the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case, where you cannot assume that $X,Y$ are independent both ways are equally correct.
In most examples, when you know whether $X,Y$ are dependent or independent the second way is more preferable (though again equally correct). If they are independent then $$Var(W)=Var(4X+6Y)=16Var(X)+36Var(Y)$$ and you do not have to include the $Cov$ term.

Comment: Actually, I should have asked first, if the exercise stipulates whether X,Y are dependent or independent. So if you do not find it useful tell me to delete it

Comment: It just says that X and Y are both binomial random variables and W = 4X + 6Y so I thought since we are looking for Var[W] and W depends on X and Y, W is not an independent variable, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Not, you only need to know whether $X,Y$ are independent or not. If it does not state anything then your way ok. If it states that $X,Y$ are independent then eliminate the $Cov$ term

Comment: Yes, ok $W$ is not independent from $X,Y$. The question you should ask is whether $X,Y$ are dependent or not. That is something that has to be stated in the exercise, you cannot find it by yourself from the given things.

Comment: Yes it doesn't state anything about them being independent. So there is no easier way to arrive at the answer?

Comment: No, give whichever you want but do not mention that "$W$ is dependent therefore...". Note also, that since E[XY] or equivalently Cov(X,Y) is not given, you can not proceed any further to a final arithmetic result. Is that ok?

Comment: Thanks, I'll make the change, but is it possible to find a joint cdf and then differentiate it to find pdf of X,Y and then get the E[XY]?

Comment: Good idea, but it is not possible to find a joint pdf of $X,Y$ when you do not whether they are dependent or not. That would be equivalent to be able to guess (with the data given) whether they are dependent or not

Comment: Even if $Cov(X,Y)=0$ (and we have no information as to whether that's the case), I don't think it's a good idea to leave off the term $2 Cov(4X,6Y)=48Cov(X,Y)$ from the expression for $Var(W)$.